# Plausible to assume that a certain random variable has a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Why it might be plausible to assume that the following random variables follow a Poisson distribution? :

$a)$ The number of customers that enter a store in a fixed time period.

$b)$ The number of customers that enter a store and buy something in a fixed time period.

$c)$ The number of atomic particles in a radioactive mass that disintegrate in a fixed time period.

$ a)$ My  Solution:

I think in this case is plausible to assume that the random variable follow a Poisson distribution because of the Law of rare events, i.e. we are considering a large number $n$ of independent events, each of which has a small success probability $\lambda/n$.

The number $n$ in this case is the number of customers that could enter the store, clearly independent. But small probability for each to actually enter.

Is my argument correct?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. A purist might say the Poison distribution involved the limit as $n\to\infty$ and so it's merely an approximation when $n$ is finite. But that degree of purity is actually a bit out of place in practical mathematical modeling.

Comment: haha ok; and b), c) are analogous cases right?

Comment: @AaronMartinez : They're "analogous" in that the same mathematical argument applies in both cases.

Comment: but in the b) case a conditional is added, 'they buy something' how can I implement the argument now?